# Putting interest rates on US states map in R

Tags: r, dictionary

How do i plot interest rate bubbles of respective states in the US on the map itself using R.
In R you have the maps library and it can draw a US states map. like so.

```
library(maps)
map("state", boundary = FALSE, col="gray", add= TRUE)
```

Now If I want to add a bubble whose diameter is the interest rate mean for that state on the map of the state. Do I first find out the capitols of the states, find their co-ordinates and then use

```
points(latCapitol, lonCapitol, col="blue",pch=19, cex=Interest.Rate )
```

for each state. Is there a simpler way. perhaps a library that already has the required information about state capitol co-ordinates. Or should I place the points in the middle of the state and not on the state capitols. PLus how would you fix the eastern states density. there are lot of small states in the north east.

Comment: You could scrape the lat/long from http://www.xfront.com/us_states/ .  People usually do this sort of thing with the points on the state centroids, which are in `state.center` in base R ... Also see `?symbols`

Comment: got it working by using data from state.center dataset in Base R

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer (please) ...

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution

Sample Fake Dataset for US States mean interest rate

```
state.mean.interest <- data.frame("State" = c("AZ", "ID", "SC", "TX", "NJ"),
                                  "Mean.Interest.Rate" = c(10, 12, 14, 11, 9))
```

Load the maps and state dataset

```
library(maps)
data(state)
```

Create a new dataframe by merging two dataframes from the state dataset

```
state.location <- data.frame ("State" = state.abb,
                              "Longitude" = state.center$x,
                              "Latitude" = state.center$y)
```

Merge the two dataframes

```
state.mean.interest <- merge(state.mean.interest, state.location)
```

Plot the US states map and the interest rate as bubbles. You can scale the bubble however, you want

```
map("state")
points(state.mean.interest$Longitude,
       state.mean.interest$Latitude,
       pch = 19,
       col = "blue",
       cex = 2* state.mean.interest$Mean.Interest.Rate/max(state.mean.interest$Mean.Interest.Rate))
```

All done. you should see a US state maps and blue color bubbles on some of the states

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one option would be to use the `googleVis` package and there then the `gVisGeoChart` function (see p. 19 in the Vignette).
Without having it tried, but I would assume that it is possible to give the city names where the bubble should be located, at least in Google Analytics they have that kind of overlay for their maps.

Answer (score 0):

I've always liked choropleth maps. The Revolution Analytics blog had a choropleth map challenge several years ago and they posted various solutions for making these maps in R. [Here is a link](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/choropleth-challenge-result.html)